# Getting error with file upload in php

Tags: php, file-upload, error-handling, runtime-error

Can anyone deduce what might be the issue here with my code? When I'm trying to upload a PDF file over 8 MB, this is the message I get:

> Something went wrong [No file uploaded]File already on server.

This is the code that I typed up:

```
    <?php
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
    $storefile_loc = "uploads/"; 
    $storefile_path = $storefile_loc.basename($name);

    //$get_ext=explode(".",$_FILES['file']['name']); //separates file name from extension
    //$ext=end($get_ext); //gets the extension from above explosion
    $txtFileType = pathinfo($storefile_path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $goodext = array("txt","doc","odt","docx"); //array of extensions for app

    //Check if files are .txt (.doc, and .pdf functionality to be added)
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])){ //checks if form has been submitted
        //$check=mime_content_type($name);
        if (($_FILES['file']['type'] == "text/plain")
        ||($_FILES['file']['type'] == "application/pdf")
        ||($_FILES['file']['type'] == "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text")
        ||($_FILES['file']['type'] == "application/msword")
        ||($_FILES['file']['type'] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
        &&(in_array($txtFileType,$goodext))){
            echo "Uploading File...";
        }
        else {
            echo "You can only upload a txt/doc/docx/pdf/odt file.";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Something went wrong [No file uploaded]";
    }

    //Check if file already exists. Probably won't need this
    if (file_exists($storefile_path)){ //this instead of $name because it's checking server
        echo "File already on server.";
    }

    //Check file size
    if  ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 2000000){
        echo "File is too large.";
    }   


    //Way to upload permanently. Probably won't need this
    /*
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $storefile_path)){
        echo "The file '".basename($_FILES['file']['name'])."' has been uploaded.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Something went wrong when uploading your file.";
    }
    */

    ?>
```

I also get notice errors on lines 2 an 36. Is the problem with my code? Or is it with Apache?

Comment: First check that `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are more than `8MB`

Comment: What errors and what is on those lines, `I also get notice errors on lines 2 an 36. Is the problem with my code?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing these settings in the php.ini, the default size ( typically ) is 8MB

```
  ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
  upload_max_filesize = 40M;
  ; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
  post_max_size = 40M;
```

And after that you have to restart your server to apply these settings.

What this means is that PHP is limiting your file upload size to these 2 settings.  You may not need 40M but you should increase it to maybe something like 120% of the largest file you want to upload, which will give you a bit of breathing room.

This is typically the first thing I configure on my servers and I usually do about 80MB, anything more then that and it's just easier for my clients to use sFTP.

Comment: That was it! Thnx so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need the add the notice error lines

`$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];`

and

```
if  ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 2000000){
    echo "File is too large.";
}
```

in to the isset('POST')

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  ...
  if  ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 2000000){
    echo "File is too large.";
  }
}
```